# How to get "true" (orthonormal) eigenvectors when I got generalized eigenvectors by solution Hv=eSv

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenfunctions, generalized-eigenvector

I solved equation $H[v] = eS[v]$ using some numerical package (`e,V = scipy.lingalg.eig(H,S)`)

There $[v]$ is matrix of all generalized eigenvectors $v_i$, $H$ is projection of operator $\hat H$ on non-orthogonal normalized basis functions $[\chi]$

$H_{ij} = \int \chi_i \hat H \chi_j$

and $S = [\chi]^T[\chi]$ is overlap matrix

$S_{ij} = \int \chi_i \chi_j$

The matrix of generalized eigenvectors $[v]$ is normalized, but it **is not ortho-normal**

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenspaces) $[v]$ it should be *S-orthogonal*, meaning $[v]^TS[v]$ is diagonal, but **not ortho-normal**. (that is right, checked it).

**But what I want** and what I mean by ***true eigenvector*** is
unitary matrix $U = [u]$ such that it transforms the non-orthogonal basis functions $[\chi]$ to orthonormal functions $[\phi]$ which diagonalize operator $\hat H$

$[\phi] = U^T [\chi] $

$\hat H \phi_i = \lambda_i \phi_i $

NOTE:

$U$ can be obtained by [Löwdin tranform](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~pdh1001/thesis/node26.html), that is solvin $(S^{-1/2} H S^{-1/2})u=\lambda u$ rather than $Hv=eSv$,  but I don't want to do that since to obtain $S^{-1/2}$ I need to diagonalize $S$-matrix, that is do two diagonalizations rather than one.

Comment: What do you mean by "true eigenvectors"? What you already have ***are*** eigenvectorsof $H$; they are expressed as column vectors in the non-orthonormal basis of $\chi_i$, but the resulting vectors (e.g. $\sum a_i \chi_i$ where $a_i$ are components of the column vectors) are the actual eigenvectors. Usually, generalized eigenvalues solvers (including the one in `scipy`) return S-orthonormal column-vectors, meaning that the resulting actual vectors will be orthonormal.

Comment: OK, maybe I have some error somewhere but when I do `phis=np.dot(Vs.T,chis)` and then `np.dot( phis.T, phis)` I don't get diagonal. (also I tried transpose it, since that is typical problem)

Comment: What are `chis` and `phis`?

Comment: as in the post above `chis` ( $[\chi]$) are basis functions and `phis` ($[\phi]$) are the eingenfunctions.

Comment: but I think the problem is elsewhere, I' working in spehrical coordinates, the `phi` is just radial function, and when I integrate I must multiply $\phi(r)$  by $4\pi r^2$... let me check it, I will return back